# HTTPContext And Controllercontext in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I read about  `HTTPContext`  And `ControllerContext` in **MVC** (fundamentalbook), but i don't know what is exactly  `HTTPContext`  And `ControllerContext`.

Could some one please explain these methods?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`HttpContext` will give information about an individual HTTP request. `ControllerContext` will give information about an HTTP request for a specified controller.

See links below for more info....

HttpContext:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.aspx

ControllerContext:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllercontext(v=vs.108).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllercontext%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

Comment: But `ControllerContext` has a property named `HttpContext`. So what's the difference?

Comment: According to .net open source code, `ControllerBase.HttpContext` is a getter wrapper for `ControllerContext.HttpContext`.